# Google Analytics Authentication Help ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, analytics

I'm trying to query google analytics in the simplest way possible but have run into a problem.
I have it done using the p12 key from google but I want it even simpler than that.
What I want is for a user to enter their google username and password and the queries will be executed using that data.
I want this done without any prompts from google asking for app permissions.
Is this possible?
Thanks,
Tommy

Answer (score 0):

Google API uses OpenAuth to authenticate users. Users **have to** consent /approve to access before they are authenticated.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, Can I not do it with just the user's google username and password only. No permission screen or anything like that. Just want the service automated for a cms where the user pops in their details and clicks yes.

Comment: No, you cannot just use the user's name and password